# php codeigniter select data

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i have a query command which run in mysql tools.

```
SELECT * FROM t_table1 WHERE id=18888
```

but when try to execute this command in php codeigniter, return no rows.
I tried to get the log process :

```
$report = array();
$report['sql'] = $this->db->last_query();
$report['error'] = $this->db->_error_number();
$report['message'] = $this->db->_error_message();
$report['aff_row'] = $this->db->affected_rows();

print_r($report);
```

there is no error message, but `affected_rows = 0`;

but those lines is in one function, sometimes it's work but when i try to change the database, it will not working.

please help..

Comment: You can post your Code igniter active query as well.

Comment: show your query code, please.

Comment: because you dont have any affected row.. you are using select query ... that bring data from your db without making any changes ... if you use any query like update delete or something which made changes on db ... thn you will get the numb of affected_rows ..

Answer (score 1):

You can try this..

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->where('whatever');
$query = $this->db->get('table');
$num = $query->num_rows();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting from database and checking affected row which will not give you the count. `Affected_rows()` is used for update and delete commands

try using

```
$this->db->from('yourtable');
[... more active record code ...]
$query = $this->db->get();
$rowcount = $query->num_rows();
```

Use `num_rows()` for getting no of rows fetched

Answer (score 0):

Try this query hope it's useful.

```
 $result = $this->db->get_where('table_name',array('id'=>'1888'));
 echo $result->num_rows();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this 2 lines of code

```
$result = $this->db->where('id', 18888)->get(t_table1)->num_rows();
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

In controller:

`$id=18888;
$this->data['get_results'] = $this->your_name_model->get_all_by_id($id);`

In model:

```
public function get_all_by_id($id){    
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('t_table1');
$this->db->where('id',$id);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
}
```

In view:

`<?php foreach($get_results as $result): echo $result['id']; ?>`